# How to calculate the a list of rasters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, raster-calculator

I'm writing ArcPy code in ArcGIS trying to calculate a list of rasters.

I get an error message that says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'.

Here's my code:

```
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env
    import os

    arcpy.env.workspace = "Z:\\comp1\\yitong\\test\\"
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    B5 = arcpy.ListRasters("*BAND_05*","")
    B4 = arcpy.ListRasters("*BAND_04*","")

    waterVapor = []

    for rasterB4 in B4:
        for rasterB5 in B5:
            print rasterB4
            print rasterB5
            partName = str(rasterB4[16:30])
            waterVaporOutputName = "waterVapor" + str(partName)
            waterVapor = 0.24+0.503*(rasterB4 - rasterB5)
            waterVapor.save(waterVaporOutputName)
```

Comment: The following line `waterVapor = 0.24+0.503*(rasterB4 - rasterB5)` is in error.  You need to convert the rasters to raster layers before you do any band math.

Comment: I tried rasterB41 = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rasterB4) before the equation, but it removed the coordinate system. Do you know who to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

try this...hopefully you won't have to fix too many syntax errors. (I don't have arcpy)

```
for rasterB4 in B4:
    for rasterB5 in B5:
        print rasterB4
        print rasterB5
        partName = str(rasterB4[16:30])
        waterVaporOutputName = "waterVapor" + str(partName)

        rasterB4 = arcpy.Raster(rasterB4)
        rasterB4 = arcpy.Raster(rasterB5)

        #i'm assuming both rasters are the same extents/cellsize
        lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(rasterB4.extent.XMin, rasterB4.extent.YMin)
        cellSize = rasterB4.meanCellWidth
        nodata = rasterB4.noDataValue

        numpy_B4 = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rasterB4)
        numpy_B5 = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rasterB5)

        waterVapor = 0.24+0.503*(numpy_B4 - numpy_B5)

        newRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(waterVapor,lowerLeft,cellSize,value_to_nodata=nodata)
        newRaster.save(waterVaporOutputName)
```

you can also remove the line above this loop-in-loop that reads "waterVapor = []"...not needed.

if you don't have a license for .asc file writing, you can try rolling your own.
[Create a Raster file out of a ASCII grid file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115024/create-a-raster-file-out-of-a-ascii-grid-file/115107#115107)

remove this:

```
newRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(waterVapor,lowerLeft,cellSize,value_to_nodata=nodata)
newRaster.save(waterVaporOutputName)
```

and put this in instead (with .asc extension)  (at the same indent, of course)

```
#write out dummy ascii raster file:
out = open('waterVaporOutputName', 'wb+')
out.write('ncols         %i\n' % numpy_B4.shape[1])
out.write('nrows         %i\n' % numpy_B4.shape[0])
out.write('xllcorner     %i\n' % rasterB4.extent.XMin)#dummy or put your own
out.write('yllcorner     %i\n' % rasterB4.extent.YMin)#dummy or put your own
out.write('cellsize      %i\n' % cellSize)
out.write('NODATA_value  %i\n' % nodata)

np.savetxt(out, waterVapor, fmt='%%.%5f')
out.close()
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this code, but there's a error message for the last line: Could not save raster dataset with output format GRID. But it has already converted numpy array to raster, why it still cannot be saved?

Comment: oh, I think I see the error...I will update it shortly.

Comment: try:  waterVaporOutputName = "waterVapor" + str(partName) + '.asc'   to give it an extension...see what happens.

Comment: I'm trying it now. There's another error: RuntimeError: ERROR 010093: Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported.Does it mean that I save it as ASCII? Why do I need to save it as ASCII? The raster format from ArcGIS doesn't work?

Comment: OK, writing to .asc file requires a license..which I guess you don't have.  Try  + '.tif' instead as a format.

Comment: some have reported success by using forward slashes instead of backslashes:   arcpy.env.workspace = "Z:\\comp1\\yitong\\test\\"  could be edited to:   arcpy.env.workspace = "Z:/comp1/yitong/test/"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this error is coming from:

```
waterVaporOutputName = "waterVapor" + str(partName)
```

which has no ArcPy code in it.  There are [numerous occurrences of it at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=typeerror%20operand%20unicode) where I think you will be best to research this as a Python rather than GIS problem.

I suspect that it is an internationalization issue.

---

On second thoughts the line I indicated above would I think only be likely to give an error of:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'unicode'.

So, the comment from @Aaron may well be a better one to pursue first.  In the meantime it is always useful to know (via an edit to your question) what line number an error like this is thrown by so that we can pinpoint the line to start looking at.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The error was from the line with the equation that Aaron pointed out.