# XYZ LiDAR data to contours with QGIS

Tags: qgis, lidar, contour, tin, xyz

I need to prepare a 1m contour map for an area with LiDAR data (XYZ files, in a 1m grid). The files are a little large and there are 54 of them. I merged the files to a single XYZ file (which turned out to be a 12GB file BTW) and imported it as a vector layer using delimited-text option.

I was hoping to use TIN interpolation and then to use contour extraction. But, for some reason, TIN interpolation is stuck at 0% even after a couple of hours.
(with pixel size set to 1.0)

I'm totally new to this. I'm not even sure if import as vector --> TIN --> extract contours is the correct way to go about things, but that's the way I saw mentioned in most places.

I tried importing individual XYZ tile, convert to TIN, then extract contours first, and it worked. But, then each tile didn't match the adjacent one.
Also, I made the merged file with this Python program, which I hope is correct (it did managed to merge the files successfully):

```py
import os
ABS_PATH = os.path.abspath(__file__)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(ABS_PATH)
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'xyz_tiles')
files = os.listdir(DATA_DIR)
with open('merged.txt', 'w') as merged:
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, file)) as f:
            for line in f:
                merged.write(line)
```

Comment: If it's gridded then it's not LiDAR it's a DTM or DEM generated from LiDAR. XYZ is the most wasteful and cumbersome format to work with, use Raster::Translate and convert to GeoTIFF or ERDAS IMG then you can run contour (gdal contour https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html) on the raster. If the data is not gridded but irregular then convert from XYZ to a vector format (Esri SHP if your data isn't too huge) before trying to TIN. It's probably taking a while because your NoData is something like -9999 and then stepping directly to real values so it's trying to contour about 10,000 intervals

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks for the reply. But no luck with Raster-Translate. It says something is wrong with a line of data. I'm now hoping to import individual xyz files as rasters and figure out a way to merge all the rasters (if there is such a way). The file is too large (12 GB) so, I don't think convert to SHP won't do (as you said it works if data isn't huge)

Comment: Perhaps then the data is irregular, read the first dozen rows and see if they have a regular step, if not have a look at LIBLAS https://pypi.org/project/libLAS/ and create a single LAS file from the inputs.

Comment: @MichaelStimson They are irregular. I think you were correct to say the data were generated from LiDAR, because everything's perfectly in a 1m x 1m grid. Is it possible to convert each tile to SHP, then do something. I tried Lastools txt2last to get the tiles converted to .las, as some said it'll reduce file sizes drastically, but it doesn't seems to work. It returns none.

Comment: If  they're perfectly in a 1m x 1m grid then the points are regular, therefore a raster; it's when the points don't align to a grid they are considered irregular. GDAL translate should have been able to convert but I do remember something about missing points for nodata, have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115024/create-a-raster-file-out-of-a-ascii-grid-file#:~:text=You%20can%20easily%20open%20ASCII,(Convert%20format)%22%20menu *especially the last answer*. and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, it may lose regularity when attaching the tiles. For irregular gridded data, use [gdal_grid](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html) instead. Read the [Reading comma separated values](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#reading-comma-separated-values) section to create a virtual vector source dataset to grid it.